# mysql to search through multiple column

Tags: php, mysql

Below displays how data stored for three columns (morning, afternoon and evening) in table named 'posts'.

[image]

Say, user wants to search for records which matches below:

**morning = Mon,Tue**
**afternoon = Mon**

Mysql query must search through all three columns for these matching data.I managed to do this for single column eg: afternoon. But how to alter my query to search through all columns?

```
array_push($cols,$col);

array_push($days,$day);
```

part of the query that needed to be amended is below (**this searches for column named 'afternoon'**):

```
 $sql.= " AND posts.afternoon IN ('" . implode("',' ",$days) . "')";
```

var_dump($cols);

**output:**

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'morning' (length=7)
  1 => string 'afternoon' (length=9)
  2 => string 'evening' (length=7)
```

var_dump($days);

**output:**

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'Sun' (length=3)
  1 => string 'Sun' (length=3)
  2 => string 'Sun' (length=3)
```

**In nutshell**

> I need to do something like this:

```
$sql .= " AND posts.".$cols." IN ('" . implode("',' ",$days) . "')";
```

> In the above query, `$cols` hold value in array or single value. You
>   may refer the value of the array for `$cols` above.Or can I use `IN
>   ('" . implode("',' ",$days) . "')` for $cols too?

Comment: you can use find in set function of mysql

Comment: Checkout `find_in_set` function and better don't store comma separated data.

Comment: This si my query now, but it doesn't filter for afternoon only but showing all results instead

Comment: AND FIND_IN_SET('posts.afternoon','posts.morning,posts.afternoon,posts.evening') IN ('Sun',' Sun',' Sun') having distance <= '40' order by distance

Comment: You can do this easily using `LIKE`

Comment: @smartrahat, can show me in query please?

Comment: $sql.= " AND posts.afternoon LIKE %".$days."%"; In this query `%` is a wild card, it means `it could be anything`

Comment: @smartrahat, thank you for this. BUt my actual problem is to compare user input against morning, afternoon and evening. Just for an example I used posts.afternoon, it could be comma separated value too like: posts.morning,posts.evening and so fort. $days actually holds this user input value.

Comment: @Keren Do you want to search all columns for a single string?

Comment: @smartrahat, I'm very sorry, its not comma separated value but array as in my posts above. array (size=3)
  0 => string 'Sun' (length=3)
  1 => string 'Sun' (length=3)
  2 => string 'Sun' (length=3)

Comment: @smartrahat, in short,how to replace AND posts.afternoon with value of $cols which actually could be array because its given by user. ANd the array value would be like, morning, afternoon and evening